# Why Proxy not working in browser (NuxtJS+Axios)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

In server rendering Proxy is working fine. Request is going to custom-server.com/v1/places. But in browser request is going to current-domain.com/api/places

Why it is not working in browser? Proxy working only in server side? Please, help.

I have NuxtJS config:

```
require('dotenv').config();

export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    buildModules: [],
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/proxy',
        ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { systemvars: true }],
    ],

    axios: {
        proxy: true,
        credentials: true,
    },
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: "http://custom-server.com",
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api' : "/v1"
            },
            changeOrigin: true,
        },
    },
}
```

My component:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return{
            placesServer:false,
            placesBrowser:false,
        }
    },
    async asyncData ({ $axios }) {
        // Here is all is fine
        let response = await $axios.get("/api/places");
        return {
            placesServer:response.data,
        };
    },
    created(){
        if (process.browser){
            // Here is not working =(
            this.$axios.get("/api/places").then((response)=>{
                this.placesBrowser = response.data;
            });
        }else{
            // Here is working fine!
            this.$axios.get("/api/places").then((response)=>{
                this.placesBrowser = response.data;
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: the first thing you need to do, is to undestand the vue life cycle. Check the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html. Inside your code you have this code: process.browser.... this means you will waiting the page load befere you run you request. So this is a wrong way, because you need to get any data before create your component, and set the data properties to use after component is created. 

you dont needed check process.browser to meke your axios request.

Comment: Another thing you can improve your abalilities is learn about vuex. Because, in vuex you have simple state, and with actions, getters and a lot of nice things to manage your state. This is right way and a very prittier, and professioanal. Take a look a docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Answer (score -1):

If your API URL is =`http://custom-server.com/api/v1/api/places`

Need to following change of Given code and need to understand the vuejs/Nuxtjs lifecyle

```
export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    buildModules: [],
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/proxy',
        ['@nuxtjs/dotenv', { systemvars: true }],
    ],

    axios: {
        proxy: true,
    },
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: "http://custom-server.com",
            pathRewrite: {
                '^/api' : ""
            },
        },
    },
}
```

and the given code inside created() hook is need to change another life cycle maybe. or need to move inside method() or as per need your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

adding `prefix` to axios in `nuxt.config.js` helped me

```js
axios: {
 proxy: true,
 credentials: true,
 prefix: '/api/'
}
```